# Find presentations of fundamental groups of topological spaces.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

We have two spaces. $X=S^1\times S^1$ without $J\times J$ where $J$ is short curve on $S^1$

We obtain second space $Y$ by gluing together two spaces like $X$ along their holes (I mean those obtained by removing $J\times J$).

I am not sure how to do it. Visually I can see that we can deform $X$ so as to obtain homotopically equivalent $S^1\vee S^1$ therefore its fundamental group is free group on two generators, but I suspect that this time I should use something stronger than such deliberations. Is there chance that is somehow follows from Seifert–van Kampen theorem or something related to it?

Comment: When you say "it's topological group" do you mean it's fundamental group? If so, the tag "topological group" should be replace with, say algebraic topology.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I did not master English terminology correctly.

Comment: I think you mean "fundamental group" not "topological group". You can formalise your argument: first use a homotopy to extend $J$ so that its range is $S^1 \setminus \{x\}$. You have now cut out all but one point on the diagonal of the [fundamental polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_(topology)#Construction_from_polygons) of the torus $S^1 \times S^1$ and you can construct a homotopy that retracts the two triangles that no longer meet along the interior of the diagonal onto the edges.

Comment: @RobArthan, could we do it in other way? After homotopic extension of $J$ we can present new space as CW-complex consisting of one 0-cell, two 1-cells and one 2-cell. It would be easy to see that what it's topological group is.

Comment: I'm not sure that you are right about the number of cells in your CW complex, but you could do it like that.